# How to secure files included in www directory

Tags: phpmyadmin, wampserver

Now I have put a password in mysql, the only security problem that is left is to secure the php files that are in my www directory.

Comment: I believe the link I posted in my answer (un-upvoted I might add!) to your related previous question contained the info to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Define what you mean by secure your php files...

Do you mean secure the code you have written or secure the php code content from being viewed by others, do you mean others on the web or other users on your machine hosting the code?

- Secure the files from www users by adding the proper document handlers in your web server config (ie, make .php executable)
- Secure the files from local users by chmod'ing to 700 or 770 (in the case that the server runs as a different user as the file owner).